# Renaming files with a year prefix from the beginning of the filename to the end

Tags: command-line, bash, files, rename

Extreme novice here attempting to figure out how to rename a bunch of files in a directory. I have hundreds of media files that all follow the same syntax for the file name:

```
year - title of movie.avi
```

I would like to write a script that removes the year and the " - " from the beginning of the file name and appends it onto the end. End result:

```
title of movie - year.avi
```

(or something similar. I don't really need the dash)

The problem I am running into with a for loop like the one below is that, since the file names have spaces in them, my script keeps parsing each word instead of each full filename.

```
for file in $(ls)
```

I haven't gotten very far as a result.

Comment: Something like `rename -n 's/(\d\d\d\d) - (.*)/$2 - $1/' *`?

Comment: @FedKad I guess you meant `rename -n 's/(\d\d\d\d) - (.*)(\..*)/$2 - $1$3/' *` :-)

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is a not so good idea ... and you don't need it ... `for file in *; do ...` will do.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa for the correction. I was just writing from memory on my tablet!

Comment: One of the rules of thumb with Linux is to never try to parse ls to do something with files. There's always a better tool.

Comment: Unless you specifically want to learn shell scripting then I'd use [krename](https://apps.kde.org/en-gb/krename/) or similar. `shellcheck` tool (try it on shellcheck.net) will show you where you're going wrong, for shell scripts in general, with not using "" to delimit strings.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `rename` command with regexp:

`rename 's/(\d+) - (.*)\.avi/$2 - $1.avi/' *.avi`

explained:

- `rename` - command (you may have to install it)
- `s/<match>/<replacement>/` (substitute command)
- `.*avi` run above on all `.avi` files

Match regex:

- `(\d+)` matches and captures group (`$1`) of one or more digits
- `-` matches literal `-`
- `(.*)` match anything and capture in group (`$2`)
- `\.avi` match `.avi` (dot is escaped)

Replacement:

- `$2 - $1.avi` - paste second group (title), then dash, then first group (year), then file extension

learn regex, <3 Regex. Steer away from using bash for looping over files, as splitting strings to tokens is hard to understand and often confusing, and you may just overlook some things if you don't understand them.

Comment: +1 Although IMHO limiting digits to 4 (year) would be more precise and capturing the extension in a group would be more portable e.g. `rename -n 's/(\d\d\d\d) - (.*)(\..*)/$2 - $1$3/' *.avi`

Comment: worked flawlessly! many thanks

Comment: Does the regex need to match the whole filename, or can it match a part of it? Would your regex match `some random movie 1234 - whatever.avi`?

Comment: @EricDuminil this regex matches a part of the name, but OP said that this is how his files look like. To match a whole filename from start to finish use start and end of line anchors in a match: `s/^<match>$/<replace>`. A note in reply to the first comment generalization works in this case but it would fail for multipart extensions, like `.tar.gz` for example, so if it's not needed I would leave it in this simple form. Another tip is that you can use `\d{4}` as 4 occurrences of digit instead of `\d\d\d\d`.

Comment: Tooster seems right to use ^ as a file might be, eg "1974 - 2001 - A space Odyssey" or "2009 - Earth 2100 - TV" or "2009 - 1066 - series" of your data isn't known to be well formed. Grep would normally only get the first match per line, but idempotency might be an issue too.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mmv.1.html) for this. First install it using:

```
sudo apt install mmv
```

Then from the directory with your files run:

```
mmv -n '???? - *.avi' '#5 - #1#2#3#4.avi'
```

The first expression (`'???? - *.avi'`) matches any file that starts with 4 characters (a `?` for each one of the 4 digits of the year), is then followed by a hyphen surrounded by spaces (`-`) and any number of any character (`*` for the title) and ends with `.avi`.

The second expression (`'#5 - #1#2#3#4.avi'`) takes each match (which is of the form `#n`) and arranges it in the way shown to achieve your desired result, i.e the tile first and the year after, separated by `-`.

The above command will show previews of the changes that will be made. If you are satisfied with them, run the command without the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 1):

In bash only:

```bash
for f in *.avi; do 
    t="${f#*- }"; t="${t%.*}"; echo mv -n -- "$f" "${t} - ${f%% *}.${f##*.}";
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do in Bash or Korn Shell is change the Internal Field Separator. By default, the $IFS includes spaces, tabs, and carriage returns or newlines. You can change the IFS to ONLY use the newline at the end of the line.

Example:

```
ORIGINAL_IFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$(echo "\n")
for LOOP in $(ls)
do
  print ${LOOP}
done
IFS="${ORIGINAL_IFS}"
```

Instead of just using print at that stage in the loop, you can use awk or cut and grab the year off the beginning of the line.

You may want to reset the IFS back to its original value before moving on to the next part of the script, in case it affects other logic.